# Multiple group counter/sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, group-by

For example, I have 2 tables. Each employee has several operations. (`operationId` is used to join)

In the database, this is Table1:

```
dbid  operationId  employeeName
-------------------------------
 1         1         emp1
 2         2         emp2
```

Table2:

```
dbid  operationName       timeStart            timeEnd
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1      working1     2022-12-19 00:00:00  2022-12-19 02:00:00  
 2      working2     2022-12-19 18:00:00  2022-12-19 21:00:00      
 3      working2     2022-12-19 00:00:00  2022-12-20 00:00:00
```

`timeStart` datatype is `datetime`.

The question is how to write a correct `select` that will show each day grouped duration of operations for each employee, like:

```
  date         hoursOfOperationsPerDay, hours   employeeName
------------------------------------------------------------
2022-12-19               5                         emp1
2022-12-19              24                         emp2
```

I know how to make group select for each day, but I don't know how to add to select employees

Comment: Have you tried `SUM` and `DATEDIFF`? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work, or what about the research you read didn't you understand?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Larnu i tried yes, it works but idk how to also take the employee for it. 
so i did datediff for duration -> datetime to date for just a day -> group by day = durations for **all** employees for each day.

Comment: Add `EmployeeName` to your `GROUP BY` too; show your attempt in your question, then we can explain why it didn't work.